# What happened to my question?

Tags: support

I was asking a question about identifying a seaplane in a photo. One time, I just saw a downvote on it and I didn’t know why it happened; there was nothing wrong with it, and it has some good amount of context.

So, why did the downvote ended up on my question for no reason? Here is the question:

[What is this seaplane shown in this photo?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/87047/34686)

Comment: Fyi, you can generate a link to any question or answer just by clicking on the "share" bottom under that question or answer, and then choosing "copy link".  Then paste it wherever you want to use it.

Comment: I have been downvoted by people who thought my question was uninformed, and still got a big score. So it's not slways a big deal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone with at least 125 reputation on the site is allowed to downvote. Unlike answers, [downvoting a question doesn't cost the voter any reputation.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) You can try asking politely in comments, but users are not required to explain their downvotes, though it's encouraged to help in improving our posts and the site as a whole.

When you get a downvote with no explanation, take a moment to step back and look at your post, try to consider other perspectives or see any improvements you could make. But don't take it personally. Different people will always have their own ideas about what makes a good post and the voting system is designed to develop an overall consensus.

In the case of your recent question, it's hard to say why someone may have downvoted it. Airplane identification is on topic and as you said you provided a good picture and extra context as well. My impression would be that the DHC-2 was a fairly well produced aircraft, and at least in some areas is still seen often, so not all people might find the identification to be interesting and useful.

Answer (score 1):

Many people would consider the Beaver on floats to be one of the most iconic floatplanes ever made, so I suspect some people thought the question-- including the suggestion that it might be a "Cessna"-- lacked research effort.

With "image search" easily accessible on the internet, some people may have thought you could have very quickly answered your own question.